# How to read a range of rows from CSV file to JSON array using PHP to handle large CSV file?

Tags: php, json, csv

The target is how to read a range of rows/lines from large CSV file into a JSON array in order to handle large files and read the data in pagination method, each page fetches a range of lines ( e.x. page number 1 fetch from line 1 to 10, page number  2 fetch from line 11 to line 20, and so and ).

the below PHP script read from the being CSV file to the desired line ($desired_line), My question is how we can determine the starting line to read from a specific line ($starting_line)

```
<?php
// php function to convert csv to json format
function csvToJson($fname, $starting_line, $desired_line) {
    // open csv file
    if (!($fp = fopen($fname, 'r'))) {
        die("Can't open file...");
    }
    
    //read csv headers
    $key = fgetcsv($fp,"1024","\t");
    
    $line_counter = 0; 
 
    
    // parse csv rows into array
    $json = array();
        while (($row = fgetcsv($fp,"1024","\t")) && ($line_counter < $desired_line)) {
        $json[] = array_combine($key, $row);
        $line_counter++; 
    }
    
    // release file handle
    fclose($fp);
    
    // encode array to json
    return json_encode($json);
}



// Define the path to CSV file
$csv = 'file.csv';
print_r(csvToJson($csv, 20, 30));

?>
```

Comment: Well if the condition `($line_counter < $desired_line)` applies an _upper_ limit, then what the counterpart for that would be, to apply a lower limit "in the other direction", should be pretty obvious, is it not?

Comment: Incorporate PHP Generator to generate line by line directly to JSON string: [PHP - json\_encode a generator object (using yield)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446268/php-json-encode-a-generator-object-using-yield)

Comment: I'm offended by this question.

Comment: You have `$starting_line` and `$desired_line` there. How about you start with figuring out how to pass them as arguments to your function; then tweak your condition. And then do a bit of research as to _whether it's possible to read specific lines only_ instead of looping until you get there. Imagine the wasted cycles with that approach in  `start 10000, until 10100`...

Comment: @MarkusAO >> For pass the starting_line  and desired_line  as arguments, I updated the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use functions like:

`fgets()` to read the file line by line

`fseek()` to move to the position of the last `fgets()` of the chunk

`ftell()` to read the position for `fseek()`

Something like this (it's only a schema):

```
<?php

...

$line_counter = 0;
$last_pos = ...
$fseek($fp,$last_pos);
while($line = fgets($fp)){ // read a line of the file
   $line_counter++;
   (...) // parse line of csv here
   if($line_counter == 100){
      $lastpos = ftell($fp);
      (...) // save the $lastpos for next reading cycle
      break;
   }
}

...

?>
```

You can also skip the `fseek()` and `ftell()` part and just count the lines every time from the beginning, but that will generally have to go through the whole file from the beginning till the desired lines.